# Singular points of non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, singularity

**EDIT**: Sorry i messed up, I forgot a minus sign in front of the left hand side. I added it now.

I am not sure how to proceed with this. Given this non-linear ODE$$\partial_{t}u(t,x)=-\cot(t)\left[\frac{1}{8u(t,x)}\left(6u(t,x)^2-4A(x)u(t,x)+B(x)\right)\right]$$
fot $t\in(0,\pi)$, can I calculate the behavior of $u(t,x)$ for $t\to0,\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\partial_{t}u(t,x)=\cot(t)\left[\frac{1}{8u(t,x)}\left(6u(t,x)^2-4A(x)u(t,x)cot(t+B(x)\right)\right]$$
Since there is no differential with respect to $x$ the equation is an ODE with the only variable $t$ and where $x$ can be considered as a parameter.
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac18 \cot(t)\left(6u-4A+\frac{B}{u}\right)$$
Let $z=\ln(\sin(t))\quad;\quad dz=\cot(t)dt$
$$\frac{du}{dz}=\frac18 \left( 6u-4A+\frac{B}{u}\right)$$
This is a separable ODE.
$$z=8\int \frac{du}{6u-4A+\frac{B}{u}}$$
$$z=\frac32\ln(6u^2-4Au+B)-\frac{4A}{3\sqrt{\frac32 B-A^2} }\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{A-3u}{\sqrt{\frac32 B-A^2}} \right)+C$$
The solution on the form of implicit equation is :
$$\ln(\sin(t))=\frac32\ln(6u^2-4Au+B)-\frac{4A}{3\sqrt{\frac32 B-A^2} }\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{A-3u}{\sqrt{\frac32 B-A^2}} \right)+C$$
$A,B,C$ are functions of $x$ :
$$\ln(\sin(t))=\frac32\ln\left(6u(x,t)^2-4A(x)u(x,t)+B(x)\right)-\frac{4A(x)}{3\sqrt{\frac32 B(x)-A(x)^2} }\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{A(x)-3u(x,t)}{\sqrt{\frac32 B(x)-A(x)^2}} \right)+C(x)$$
$${{\sin(t)=} =F(x)\bigg(6u(x,t)^2-4A(x)u(x,t)+B(x)\bigg)^{3/2} {\exp\left(-\frac{4A(x)}{3\sqrt{\frac32 B(x)-A(x)^2} }\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{A(x)-3u(x,t)}{\sqrt{\frac32 B(x)-A(x)^2}} \right) \right)}}$$
$F(x)$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to some boundary condition.

Now, coming back to the original question, answering about the behaviour of $u(x,t)$ for $t\to0,\pi$ seems problematical if no boundary condition is specified.

An hypothetical answer for any boundary condition might be 
$$6u(x,0)^2-4A(x)u(x,0)+B(x)\sim 0$$
$$u(x,0)\sim \frac{2A(x)\pm\sqrt{4A(x)^2-6 B(x)}}{6}$$

NOTE :

This result is suggested by inspection of the original equation where $\cot(t)$ tends to infinity for $t\to0$. Then, most likely $6u(t,x)^2-4A(x)u(t,x)+B(x)\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot a minus sign in my original post. In your calculation, this would mean that the exponent is $-3/2$. Hence the term in the bracket has to diverge to positive infinity for $t\to 0,\pi$, right?

Comment: No, it is not so simple. In fact the change of variable is $z=\ln|\sin(t)|$. In the above simplified explanation, in interest of space, the sign was first determined for consistency with the original equation around $t=0$. Sorry, I hate the fact that I have to restart a study due to a mistake of the OP. But, without doing it, I am confident that the result will be also $6u(x,0)^2-4A(x)u(x,0)+B(x)=0$.

Comment: I apologize and I am very thankful, your answer helped me none the less. However, I am not sure what exactly the problem is. With the minus sign, Mathematica gives the same implicit solution of the ODE as yours above but with a negative exponent of the quadratic form. This means, using the limit of $x\to 0,\pi$ on love sides has to result in a divergent $u$ I would say, since the other $u$ term in $\tan^{-1}$ is bounded. Of course, if $\mathrm{d}u/\mathrm{d}t=0$, then $6u(t,x)^2-4A(x)u(t,x)+B(x)=0$ gives two regular solutions of the ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the equation as an ODE in $t$ (which it is): the equation is first order and separable, so can be solved explicitly by integration. You obtain the equation
$$
\sin(t) = f(u),
$$
with $f(u)$ a function involving arctan and exp. This equality holds for all $t$ (and all $x$), so taking $t \to 0,\pi$ makes the left hand side zero. So, $u$ will converge to the zeroes of $f$ when $t \to 0,\pi$. So, all you have to do is find $f$, and determine its zeroes.